# AEM6: how to append a css to a component directly

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I want to change a radio button label currently from the right to left.

how to append a css to a component directly without creating a client lib.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `style` property available for the widget to specify custom style which would be applied only to that component's element.

Quoting the docs, it can either be a

> A style specification string e.g. 'width:100px', or object in the form {width:'100px'}, or a function which returns such a specification.

For more info, check the [Radio Widget API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.Radio) or the [Selection Widget API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection)

Answer (score 0):

You could use style to have css at the component level as suggested in previous post.
**Or** If you are using radio OOTB component, you can make this option author-able so that user can change label without making any code/css changes.